# Launch a Modal window from within another modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am using jQuery Modal: [rsModal](http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Simplest-jQuery-Modal-Window-Plugin-rsModal.html)

I can launch this modal from a button fine, but I would to be able to click a button from within the first modal to open another modal closing the first.

I copied the same button which launches the first modal into the modal content and changed which Modal that button launched, clicking it does nothing. Almost like the button just doesn't respond while in thyme modal.

Button to launch the first Modal:

```
<div class="cust-btn"><li><a href="#" class="myModal_advanced_options">Advanced Options</a></li></div>
```

That button launches this modal:

```
<!-- Advanced Options Modal -->
<div id="modalcontent" class="modal modal_advanced_options">
    <div class="cust-btn"><li><a href="#" class="myModal_new_cust">New Card</a></li></div>
</div>
```

Clicking the button inside this modal I would like to close the first and open the second. Here is the script which calls the modal content:

```
/* Advanced Options Modal */
    $(function(){
        $('.myModal_advanced_options').click(function(){
            $('.modal_advanced_options').rsModal();
        });
    });
```

The button inside the modal should then call this function to launch the next modal:

```
/* New Customer Modal */
    $(function(){
        $('.myModal_new_cust').click(function(){
            $('.modal_card').rsModal();
        });
    });
```

Anyone have any ideas? Is this even possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* New Customer Modal */
    $(function(){
        $('.myModal_new_cust').click(function(){
            $('#modalcontent').hide();
            $('.modal_card').rsModal();                
        });
    });
```

try this if it can solve your problem ....

Comment: Nope. No luck. Clicking the button inside the modal just does nothing.

Comment: First Modal still not closing? Or it is closing but its wrapper not closing?

Comment: Sorry I should have said. The first modal remains open.

Comment: i am not sure about rsModal() funtion you are using...so can you try it with bootstrap modal. You will find no such difficulty in it...